# Why would you use AWS Lambda/API Gateway to serve up HTML content vs. S3 bucket for serverless architecture

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm on a project where the client is serving up the HTML markup of their website via AWS Lambda/API Gateway.  I've not seen this approach before.

The best I could find as an explanation was here:
[How to build front end for Microservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404800/how-to-build-front-end-for-microservices)

If someone could tell me what are the benefits of this approach vs. just throwing the .html file in a S3 bucket or another server would be, that would be much appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

The goal of the Lambdas as I understand them is the exact opposite. You want to use them to create the back-end webservices that the front-end can access from a S3 bucket or any other server. I have used the S3 html -> API Gateway -> Lambdas to create a microservices architecture very effectively.

Using Lambdas directly as the front-end would only make sense if you want to expose as little of the code as possible or if your front-end will be non html (e.g. IoT?). You could have a Front-end Lambda -> API Gateway -> Back-end Lambdas microservices architecture that exposes only the output html or similar (kind of php development vs. javascript).

My opinion is that it will make development a lot more costly and the user interface will suffer. You generally don't want to reinvent the webserver unless there is a security reason for it.

Comment: Thank you.  I agree that your approach is one I have used in the past and one I see being used consistently with others.  I just wanted to know if there was something I was missing.